# Why can't I offer a bounty

Tags: support

I have a question here which I would really like an answer to but I don't have an option to offer a bounty.

[How to compare fields in Meteor find query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561664/how-to-compare-fields-in-meteor-find-query)

Comment: Because you need 75 rep to do so...

Comment: @markhorrocks, I've start a bounty for You. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @markhorrocks, let me know who should receive bounty points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum required reputation to offer a bounty is 75. See the [Set Bounties privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).